# S3 credentials in COPY INTO not working with session variables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Running this in a worksheet I'm expecting the data to be loaded into my_table:

```
SET AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='XXXX';
SET AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='XXXX';

COPY INTO my_table (name,dog_name) FROM s3://my-bucket/*.csv
credentials=(aws_key_id='$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' aws_secret_key='$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
file_format=(type=csv field_delimiter=',' empty_field_as_null=true compression=gzip
field_optionally_enclosed_by='"');
```

But I'm getting `Failure using stage area. Cause: [The AWS Access Key Id you provided is not valid.]`.

Replacing the variables directly with value is working, am I missing something?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from around the variables. You're sending the literal strings $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY instead of the values they represent because they're wrapped inside single quotes.

Comment: Thx @GregPavlik but removing them give me this error: `SQL compilation error: invalid value [$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID] for parameter 'aws_key_id'`

Comment: Interesting... I also tried changing them from session variables to a UDF returning a string and the copy into statement didn't like having a UDF return there either. It's possible the credentials section supports only string literals. It will be interesting if someone's done this and can comment.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of doing this?  It would be easier to create a stage using the credentials and then just referencing the stage instead of the S3 location.

Comment: @MikeWalton the purpose hide the credentials when loading from S3. Not sure to understand why it is easier creating a stage first, you still need the credentials.

Comment: Yes, but once an administrator sets up the stage, no user needs to see the credentials, so you've essentially hidden them.  You could also use STORAGE INTEGRATIONS and remove the need for the keys altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in the `SET` command here is a [SQL variable](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html) which can't be passed as an option inside a `COPY INTO` command dynamically, you can create a Stored Proc to use for this scenario, try using the following:

```
create or replace procedure execute_copy_into(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID STRING,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY STRING)
    returns string
    language javascript
    execute as CALLER
    as
    $$
    var sql_command="COPY INTO my_table (name,dog_name) FROM s3://my-bucket/*.csv \
                  credentials=(aws_key_id='"+AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID+"' aws_secret_key='"+AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY+"') \
                  file_format=(type=csv field_delimiter=',' empty_field_as_null=true compression=gzip \
                  field_optionally_enclosed_by='"'); "
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
       {
       sqlText: sql_command
       }
      );
    var rs = stmt.execute();
// Looping to return all files processed
        while (rs.next())  {
      result += rs.getColumnValue(1) + "\n";
      }
return result;
    $$
;
// Now call the stored proc

SET AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='XXXX';
SET AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='XXXX';
CALL execute_copy_into($AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);

// Or just eliminate the variables and call it without

CALL execute_copy_into('XXXX','XXXX');
```